# Using \ for template of html in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is it I got error of unexpected illegal of TOKEN using below code?

```
var html = '<div id="wrap">\
    <img style="width:100%;display:block">\
  <div>\'

  console.log(html);
```

I use `\` to escape, it should work fine..

Comment: `<div>\'` ==> `<div>';` You're escaping the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
<div>\'
```

You are escaping the closing quote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var html = '<div id="thermal-close-sales-wrap">\
    <img style="width:100%;display:block">\
  <div>'

  console.log(html);
```